# Why does heating eggs not change the State of matter from solid to liquid

Tags: thermodynamics, states-of-matter

i'm not sure how much sense this question makes, but my physical education is not very great, so i'm just curious.

Normally, when we heat matter, it changes the state it at some level, but eggs don't - or at least in the "wrong" order, namely from liquid to solid. But why doesn't heating eggs make the "content" more liquid?

I know that heating kind of "extracts" the liquid in the matter, but i don't think that is relevant for that issue.

Anyways, is there a "higher" reason that eggs fall out of this principle?

Comment: Hi toogley, the post I've linked ass exactly the same question as you do.

Comment: @JohnRennie Soory for the duplicate, i hadn't found that post